# how to create a list containing of 100 number of strings whose names are in series

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

a list of string objects is like

```
nodes=["#A_CN1","#A_CN2","#A_CN3","#A_CN4","#A_CN5","#A_CN6","#A_CN7","#A_CN8","#A_CN9","#A_CN10"]
```

Here in the above list there are 10 elements but i need to use around 100 elements and the element is like **#A_CN100**

Is there any way to represent it shortly rather than writing 100 times in python ?

If suppose there is a list of 100 elements where each element itself is a list like, node1 , node2.. all are some lists

```
nodes=[node1,node2,node3,node4,node5,node6....node100]
```

if I express this as

```
nodes=[node{0}.format(i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

But,this throws an error! How to rectify this?

Comment: Your updated question isn't clear at all. Shouldn't you have at least posted a sample of what node1, node2 looks like??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A one liner with list comprehensions

```
nodes = ["#A_CN{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

There is also a suggestion in the comments that a generator version be demonstrated. It would look like this:

```
nodes = ("#A_CN{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,101))
```

But more commonly this is passed to list

```
nodes = list("#A_CN{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,101))
```

So we end up with the same result as the list comprehension. However the second form is useful if you want to *generate* about a million items.

Comment: great answer, +1, but i would edit and add `nodes=` to fit his question and to avoid confusion. also, if it's going to be iterated on only once, perhaps a generator is better than a list (even though the question was specifically about a list)

Comment: now if nodes are like= [node1, node2 , node3, node4.... node100] and  each element is ltself a list.[node{0}.format(i) for in range(1,101)] won't be valid , how to rectify this case?

Comment: That wasn't what you asked.

Comment: Again that's not what you asked. I have answered the question you asked. Please post another one but this time please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first and remember to include all the details

Comment: brother i have to wait for 90 mins for posting as new question, its getting late why don't you please answer here brother @e4c5

Comment: If you read that link, and update the question, I *might* be able to give it a shot. What you have said in the comment isn't very clear at all. But next time you answer a question please do follow the guidelines in that link and also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay brother now i have edited the question is it clear now, if so how to resolve @e4c5?

Comment: no you have made it worse. Don't edit the question to invalidate the existing anser.

Comment: I am bit new to stack overflow brother, don't mind the mistake i have done, so now i can't update the question, can't write a new question what can i do? if u have seen the question after i have changed please answer it bro @e4c5

Comment: You can edit the question to add new content. This is my last response on this comment thread.

Comment: what is the mistake i have done why did people down-voted my question, now i am unable to ask question. Sorry for my mistake, can any one  kindly please upvote or remove the downvote who had done and  decrease the -2 to 0 please.

Comment: Your down votes didn't come from me, but your mistake was to not follow the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
as I repeatedly asked you to.

Comment: I have read those now, I will give my best while asking my further questions thanks for suggestion @e4c5

Comment: great all the best, here an up from me

Answer (score 1):

You omitted quotes (or apostrophes). Instead of

```
nodes=[node{0}.format(i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

use

```
nodes=["node{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

Comment: Won't the elements in the list become strings if we put the quotes , that is the reason i haven't put. Actually, these are not strings they are names of class instances.

Comment: **Please help us help you.** Expand your answer and show us an example of an input and output. Btw. *regardless of the value of* `node`,  the `node{0}` has *no meaning* (syntax error), and the `format()` method is applicable only for *strings*.

Comment: sorry I am not able to put a new question,  it's giving like vol of spam has increased. So can u please upvote the question and make it 0 from -1 . I will be really grateful to u ! @MarianD